# Is "urg_node" supported for groovy?

Tags: ros, laser, urg-node, hokuyo, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have ROS groovy running on my machine. I need to get a Hokuyo urg-04lx work there. Can I install urg_node on Groovy or do I have to change my ROS distribution?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271038/is-%22urg_node%22-supported-for-groovy?/) by [Yaser](https://answers.ros.org/users/18121/yaser/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-09-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to [the wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/urg_node) it is supported from Groovy through Kinetic. To install [the source](https://github.com/ros-drivers/urg_node/tree/groovy-devel), you can clone the repo, checkout the `groovy-devel` branch and then compile it. I don't believe that you can use `apt` to install as this is quite old (the most recent commit for the `groovy-devel` branch was 5 years ago).

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-09-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Yaser](https://answers.ros.org/users/18121/yaser/) on 2017-09-16**:
Thank you Jayess,
But as you see there is no link for groovy install. Should I try installing all the dependencies?

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-09-16**:
The link was there, you just have to click on any other tab *besides* Groovy.